# Google Auto Suggest by Country

Tags: autocomplete, jsonp

I'd like to make a search box that returns google auto suggest responses from different countries. I found this great example of recreating an autocomplete search:

http://jsfiddle.net/XxTuA/2/

```
var suggestCallBack; // global var for autocomplete jsonp
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=?",
                { 
                  "hl":"en", // Language                  
                  "jsonp":"suggestCallBack", // jsonp callback function name
                  "q":request.term, // query term
                  "client":"youtube" // force youtube style response, i.e. jsonp
                }
            );
            suggestCallBack = function (data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data[1], function(key, val) {
                    suggestions.push({"value":val[0]});
                });
                suggestions.length = 5; // prune suggestions list to only 5 items
                response(suggestions);
            };
        },
    });
});
```

but I can't figure out how to limit it to a specific country, and there doesn't seem to be documentation of paramaters that can be passed to google auto suggest.

If anyone has suggestions on how to accomplish this, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete search suggestions are determined by language not by country.

Just set the `hl` to a different language.

For more info see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/x8yfm/

Comment: I do not think this is true, I am in switzerland and while doing an English query of "what is" (even using the link above), I get "what is the capital of Switzerland" as the top query. I doubt that is one of the main world wide "what is" questions...

Comment: Autocomplete search options also vary by country. In Uzbekistan and Russia they speak Russian. But suggestions in Tashkent and in Moscow are different.

Comment: The behavior is naturally different now, 6 years after the answer, but  this was the case, back in 2014.